# Symfony2 FOSUSER invalid resource

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, fosuserbundle

i'm trying to setup a simple FOSUser instance on my new symfony2 project (v2.8) i've followed the tutorial on the documentation exactly as it says. And i'm getting the current error

```
    InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 317:
Unrecognized option "resource" under "fos_user"
in ArrayNode.php line 317
at ArrayNode->normalizeValue(array('db_driver' => 'orm', 'firewall_name' => 'main', 'user_class' => 'AuthBundle\Entity\User', 'resource' => '@FOSUserBundle\Resources\config outingll.xml')) in BaseNode.php line 264
at BaseNode->normalize(array('db_driver' => 'orm', 'firewall_name' => 'main', 'user_class' => 'AuthBundle\Entity\User', 'resource' => '@FOSUserBundle\Resources\config outingll.xml')) in Processor.php line 33
at Processor->process(object(ArrayNode), array(array('db_driver' => 'orm', 'firewall_name' => 'main', 'user_class' => 'AuthBundle\Entity\User', 'resource' => '@FOSUserBundle\Resources\config outingll.xml'))) in Processor.php line 50
at Processor->processConfiguration(object(Configuration), array(array('db_driver' => 'orm', 'firewall_name' => 'main', 'user_class' => 'AuthBundle\Entity\User', 'resource' => '@FOSUserBundle\Resources\config outingll.xml'))) in FOSUserExtension.php line 45
at FOSUserExtension->load(array(array('db_driver' => 'orm', 'firewall_name' => 'main', 'user_class' => 'AuthBundle\Entity\User', 'resource' => '@FOSUserBundle\Resources\config outingll.xml')), object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 55
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 107
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 593
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in Kernel.php line 511
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 133
at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 182
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 30
at require('/home/sergio/Desktop/RSU/web/app_dev.php') in router_dev.php line 40
```

at config.yml i got the current identation

```
    # fos
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AuthBundle\Entity\User
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle\Resources\config\routing\all.xml"
```

Everything is as in the tutorial, i commented the "resource" part and i could update DB schema, symfony can't find the FOSUserBundle\Resources\config\routing\all.xml it seams. any suggestion how to solve this ?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the resource key under fos_user in routing.yml

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

**Documentation:**

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files

Comment: ty, was probably blind -.-